# How to write a query for JpaRepository in case of ManyToMany relation in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I an trying to write a correct method of a JpaRepository and I just don't get it.
I have a following situation:
2 Entities: User and Room

```
public class User implements UserDetails {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Room> rooms;
...
}
```

```
public class Room {
    ...
    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> users;
...
}
```

so, 1 user can be member of multiple rooms and 1 room includes multiple users.
I have automatically generated tables - users, room and room_users.
room_users looks basically like this:

| room_id | users_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |

I need a method to collect all users from a room by a room id. It seems simple enough but I can't wrap my head around this problem (I'm a noobie).

I tried this:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findUsersByRoomsId(Long roomId);
}
```

or just findByRoomsId (I also can't understand the difference, really), but method is returning an empty List.

Would be glad to hear any thoughts on this issue.

I tried to read this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) and failed to find a working solution there.

Comment: On ManyToMany relations you should always use Set instead of List.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. I also found another part a problem, I have a users_rooms table which was not filled automatically. I filled it manually and the method worked, so may be I should try fix that issue too.

Comment: One way would be to use `findById` or whatever your Id is named. You then get an Optional and if successfull you can retrieve the users with the getter on your entity. Depending on whether youre Lazy loading or not (you should definitefly always set onetomany and manytomany on lazy load) you may also declare to fetch the User then eagerly (you can do that with eg an EntityGraph annotation)

Comment: You might also get the users when calling the getUser() getter on the Room entity as long as you're within an upright Transaction, but although the result would be what oyu want, it would cost an extra trip to the database. So better tell yout JPA provider (Hibernate?) directly within the initial statement what you want.

Comment: "get an Optional and if successfull you can retrieve the users with the getter on your entity. " this is a genius solution, I tried it and it worked! Thank you very much!